# How to run automated tests of In-App purchases in Sauce Labs with Appium

Tags: appium, in-app-billing, saucelabs

I am trying to run tests for In-App payments for both iOS and Android with Appium.

So far I have managed to run a local instance of Appium and connect my test devices to it. All the tests work fine. Now I need to run them on Sauce Labs.

According to [Sauce Labs' FAQ](https://docs.saucelabs.com/mobile-apps/faq/#can-other-users-access-my-data) all the data (including Google Play profiles) from test devices is cleaned up after running tests.

Is it possible to provide the required credentials to Sauce Labs for both iOS and Android? If yes, how? Browserstack [supports In-App payment testing](https://www.browserstack.com/app-automate/device-features#google-in-app-purchase) and you can even send the credentials as one of desired capabilities. Is it possible to do the same for Sauce Labs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, this isn't possible for public devices, but it *might* be possible with private devices.

Sauce Labs currently needs access to the accounts signed in on the devices.  With private devices, they could set up a shared account to which they have access, but configured with your billing details.

You'd have to talk to your account manager to ask about Private device access; It's a contract-only service.